# How to Migrate MySQL schema to SQL Server CE?

Tags: sql-server-ce, database-migration

I am aware of SQL Server Migration Toolkit for MySQL. But I want to migrate the schema to SQL Server CE. Is there any way to do with Migration Toolkit. Or alternatively, if I first migrate to SQL Server then how to replicate the schema changes to SQL Server CE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some free tools, that allow you to migrate from SQL Server to SQL Server Compact - http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com (Export2sqlce.exe from command line)